# OpenPopUpPage not showing a popup

Tags: javascript, calendar, sharepoint-on-prem, 2019, react

I have a SharePoint 19 web part written in React and I am trying to execute a function OpenPopUpPage which displays the content of some calendar events. If I type `OpenPopUpPage('http://sp2019/sites/test/Lists/testcalendar/DispForm.aspx?ID=24')` in the browsers command line it opens a popup for the event with ID number 24. I want to replicate that in my webpart with `<a onClick={()=>{"javascript:OpenPopUpPage('http://sp2019/sites/test/Lists/testcalendar/DispForm.aspx?ID=24')"}}>Show more!</a>`
but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve the issue:

```
<a href="javascript:OpenPopUpPage('http://sp2019/sites/test/Lists/testcalendar/DispForm.aspx?ID=24')"}}>Show more!</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need the "javascript:" prefix bit, or quotes around the whole thing because that turns it into a *string* of the function call you are trying to make, and not the function call itself.

Maybe try:

```
<a onClick={()=>{OpenPopUpPage('http://sp2019/sites/test/Lists/testcalendar/DispForm.aspx?ID=24')}}>Show more!</a>
```

Comment: My typescipt couldn't find the function OpenPopUpPage which gets "loaded" when you open Sharepoint 19 on premise page.